# For a nonsingular quasi-affine variety $X$ and finitely many points in $X$, there exists a affine open that contain those points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is from Shafarevich's text "Basic Algebraic Geometry I" :

[image]

May I ask why it is possible to choose one affine open set that can contain all these points? We know that every point in a quasi-projective variety is locally affine, but the proof requires looking at the standard affine piece of $P^n$ and the intersection of those affine piece with $X$, but there is no way to say that $x_1,......,x_m$ all belong to the same affine piece.

Comment: I haven't actually read Shafarevich's book, but does he define varieties as being quasi-projective?

Comment: actually, his definition does not even require a variety to be irreducible like in most other texts but we can assume it is, but its basically any affine, quasi-affine, projective, quasi-projective algebraic set.

Comment: I am wondering if this helps: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09NJ

Comment: I am in the middle of learning about schemes so I still don't know what a separated subschemes are yet, but i think if we translate everything to varieties, it should be correct. Thank you

Comment: The linked duplicate explains that any quasi-projective variety has this property. For you, with a quasi-affine variety, the solution can be made a bit simpler: embed your variety $X$ as an open subset of an affine variety $\overline{X}$ with complement $Y$, then consider the surjection from the coordinate ring $k[\overline{X}]\to k[Y]\times k[x_1]\times\cdots\times k[x_m]$. By the Chinese remainder theorem, we can find an element $f$ of $k[\overline{X}]$ which is $0$ in $k[Y]$ and $1$ in each $k[x_i]$, and taking $D(f)$ you get your desired affine open neighborhood containing all the $x_i$s.